# Why does c# "&&" operator give this error of "cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'"

Tags: c#, operators

BH  I'm not sure why I keep getting this error when I input the following code or variations thereof:

```
        int age = 20;
        int score = 49;
        int crazy = 100;
        if (age = 20 && score  < 50 || score > 95) {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome");     }
```

Here's the error: error CS0019: Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

Can someone in this wonderful community please help?  Thanks!

Comment: it's `==` not `=` to compare. And use parenthesis. `((age == 20) && (score  < 50)) || (score > 95)`... or wait, do you mean `(age == 20) && ((score  < 50) || (score > 95))`

Comment: [Equality operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators)

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note here is that when C# makes an assignment (puts a value into a variable) it also returns the value that was assigned. This:

```
age = 20
```

Returns a value, 20

You could use this in another assignment:

```
score = age = 20;
```

Age is 20 because we assigned the value to it and it returned 20. Score is also 20 because we assigned the return value of (age=20) to it. Assigning (the result of assigning age) to score also returned a value..  and we could go on like that forever:

```
a=b=c=d=e=f...=x=y=z=20; //all 26 variables now have a value of 20
```

---

We can treat the return values as elements of a sum just like any other:

```
score = (age = 20) + 1;
```

Assigns 20 to age and 21 to score, and returns 21

---

We can change types, just like we can say `myString = 20.ToString()` (yep, you can call methods on a constant just like you can on a variable) we can say this:

```
myString = (score = (age = 20) + 1).ToString();
```

Assigns 20 to age, 21 to score then turns the returned 21 into a string and assigns "21" to myString

--

Ok, so enough of that silliness.. but hopefully you can see why

```
if(age = 20 && score < 50)
```

Is giving the error it does. `age` is set to 20, 20 is being returned, and is being `&&`ed with (score<50), an operation that returns a boolean. This means it's like you wrote this:

```
age = 20;
if(20 && score < 50)
```

Which plain up doesn't work. Good job this isn't JavaScript.

**And of course, it's most likely you wanted to use `==` to do a compare of age, not `=` to do an assignment..**

..just remember that assignments result in values too, which is why this crazy looking loop works:

```
while(null != x = stream.Read()) //loop while Read() doesn't return null
{
  //use x, which certainly has a non null value 
}
```

I'd exercise caution in using compound assignment-and-comparison statements though - they're a lot less readable than spelling these things out step by step:

```
for(x = stream.Read(); x != null; x = stream.Read())
```